# Excluding a directory in .htaccess from domain root

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, drupal-6

I have a drupal installed in our main domain.  http://domain.com

And a Wordpress installed in a directory domain.com/directory

Sometimes when I accessed the wordpress from **domain.com/directory** it delivers me to domain.com/

Heres a part of .htaccess from the domain root..

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

What should I do to exclude domain.com/directory from domain root in DRupal?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to add this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory [NC]
```

So that it now looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the url as `http://domainname.com/wordpress_directory/` into `siteurl` and `home` values from the database table `wp_options`.